# How to upload excel file to system via jmeter

Tags: jmeter

My excel contains account related data. Once i upload this in to system and click on the upload button system automatically create accounts. Plz tell me the steps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39249674/how-can-i-upload-xls-file-in-jmeter this post may helps.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest and the easiest way is just recording your file upload event using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder):

1. Prepare JMeter for recording.

   - From JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Expand `Workbench -> HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder` and click "Start"
2. Prepare Browser for recording

   - You need to configure your browser to use JMeter as a [proxy](https://library.medicine.yale.edu/services/computing/configure-browser), if JMeter and browser are running on the same machine use `localhost` as proxy host and `8888` as proxy port.
3. Copy the file you would like to upload into "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. This is vital as if you omit this step JMeter won't be able to locate the file. See [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter) for more detailed explanation
4. Upload your file in browser - JMeter will capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler for this.